# how did this term happened?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

[image]

here is the pedal form of curvature and $\psi=\theta+ \phi$ . Then how $$\sin \phi = r \frac{d\theta}{ds} ,\cos\phi=\frac{dr}{ds}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\hat{n}$ be the unit vector normal to it. The curve itself is given by $\vec{r}=f(\theta)\hat{r}$. 
Writing the curve equation as $F(r,\theta)=r-f(\theta)$, we immediately note that
$$
\hat{n}=\pm \frac{\nabla F}{|\nabla F|}=\pm \left(f(\theta)\hat{r}+f'(\theta)\hat{\theta}\right)\frac{d\theta}{ds}
\Longrightarrow
\hat{n}ds=\left(r\hat{r}+\frac{dr}{d\theta}\hat{\theta}\right)d\theta \qquad (*)
$$
where in the above we have used the fact that in polar coordinates $$ds=\sqrt{dr^2+r^2d\theta^2}=\sqrt{f(\theta)^2+f'(\theta)^2}d\theta$$
and that $\nabla F=(\partial F/\partial r)\hat{r}+r^{-1}(\partial F/\partial \theta)\hat{\theta}$. Let us know take the inner product of equation (*) with $\hat{r}$, to obtain
$$
(\hat{n}\cdot \hat{r})ds=rd\theta
$$
But $(\hat{n}\cdot \hat{r})=\cos (\pi/2-\phi)=\sin \phi$, meaning $\sin \phi \:ds = r\:d\theta$. Taking the inner product with $\hat{\theta}$ instead we find 
$$
(\hat{n}\cdot \hat{\theta})ds=dr\Longrightarrow \cos \phi \: ds=dr
$$
I have intentionally been very concise, left some little details unexplains because you should try to fill in the blanks yourself.